# Casting type with Omit in typescript

Tags: typescript

Or why following [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmRAFcBbAI2gG4c8KjTLosBfLLMATwAcUAhZAF5cAeTLAwAHlQAaZAHIKCgHy0sCAPYgAzmGSaKAK1RF0IjIWQBGeQ2QAmVrS279ho4JEf0cHcn51Vx1NABsIADpQzQBzAAoFDwgEfVMFeR8AShdtEPCo2ISPfnSDY35srCA) doesn't remove member 'b' from resulting object?

```
interface A {
    a: number;
    b: number
}

type B =  Omit<A, 'b'>;

const objA: A = {a: 1, b: 2};
const objB: B = objA as B;

console.log('object A:', objA);
console.log('objB', objB);
```

Instead of :

```
"objB",  {
  "a": 1
}
```

I got :

```
"objB",  {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
```

Comment: Because it's just a type? You seem to be confused about the difference between types and values. The only Typescript thing that exists at runtime are `enum`s

Comment: There’s no “casting” in TS the way you’re thinking about it. If you want to remove properties you need to do it yourself at runtime, maybe with an `omit` helper function.

Comment: @jcalz, yup, figured it out, using lowdash omit function

Answer (score 0):

Omit is for the type. This has nothing to do with the value or shape of objects.

You have made the operation on `type A` to get a new `type B`. There is no change made to `objA,objB`.

With this statement:

```
const objB = objA as B;
```

you are forcing the TypeScript compiler to see the type of `objB` differently. The JavaScript Interpreter(/Compiler) still sees the same value. TypeScript does not get added in the bundle and is just a language used while development.

PS: You can check basics of TypeScript works.

Comment: Understood, but if type 'B' is literally ignored, I'm left to leverage 'omit' only on object creation, something like const objB: B = {b:1}; In that case I really don't need 'omit' and can create brand new type

Comment: Yes, mostly. Also if you want to make a similar type not for an object created but ann object already being used. Think of react props object, you do not create them technically.

Comment: @krul you may not for your use case. But what is the return type of the following function: `function foo(a: A) { delete a.b; return a; }`? (Hint, it's `Omit<A, 'b'>`).

Comment: :) I guess it's a ```A```

Comment: @krul but `A` has a `.b` property. The object returned from `foo` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith , but hope you agree that ```const objB: B = objA as B;``` leads to dishonest type representation ?

Comment: @krul no I don't agree. Typescript is structurally typed: `objA` is a perfectly valid `B`. The type `B` says you will *at least* have an `a` property that's a number. It doesn't say "and nothing else". I gave you a real world example of when you'd want to specify *at the type level* the removal of the property, in this case when you remove the property from the value at runtime.

Comment: @JaredSmith guess I need to brush up typescript basics, anyway, I've end up using lowdash omit which served purpose, thanks for pointers

Comment: @JaredSmith type B in my simplistic mind is declared as the type deriving from type A but **dropping** field b, that's what I'm confused with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257255/discussion-between-krul-and-jared-smith).